# changing a local registry key with PHP

Tags: php, windows, registry

I'm creating a PHP script in other to automate a browser performance test. One of the key features is to be able to enable / disable a plugin in Internet Explorer or Firefox. 
Reading about it online, I saw I have to execute a similar command to :

```
 [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions\{6D53EC84-6AAE-4787-AEEE-F4628F01010C}]
   “Flags”=dword:00000001
```

In otehr to accomplish what I need. However, my question is: how can I accomplish that through PHP? I thought about using `exec('cmd')` but I'm not sure whether that's the correct way.
Does someone have done that before? The script is local only, and always going to work on Windows environment.

Thank you

Comment: do you want to change the registry of your users remotely?

Comment: While you seem to have a reasonable question (and yes, probably easiest thing to do is `exec` a Windows command) my response upon reading that subject could be summarized by: o_O

Comment: @dimo414 - I think he's referring to PHP's exec function...which would only execute commands on the server his script is running...

Comment: Agreed, that is what I assume is being done.  I've updated the question title since I suspect the downvotes are coming from people assuming OP is asking about remote modification.

Comment: @dimo414 How do you *know* the OP is asking for a local modification? I've rolled back your edit until the OP can confirm if this is local or remote.

Comment: @bwoebi the script runs locally ... and the reason I'm doing in PHP is because I'm using an API which is either in PHP or JavaScript

Comment: @DannyBeckett It's local, and always going to run in a Windows environment ( I know, I don't like this, but my co-worker insists so)

Comment: @DannyBeckett because if the question is regarding a local change it's a reasonable question, and if not the question should simply be closed / deleted, and because people were mass-downvoting it under the no-better-assumption the question was regarding remote changes.

Comment: @dimo414 Indeed, since the change is a local one, it *is* a reasonable question. I've upvoted the question now. At the time though, you didn't *know* it was local, so your edit was incorrect, at that moment in time.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you can only do this running a PHP script locally on a Windows machine, it is not possible* to modify the Windows Registry of some other machine that just sends a request to a PHP script on your server.

But you should be able to run exec in order to change the local machine, some quick googling returned [how to delete and add registry keys from the command line](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/04/05/how-to-delete-and-add-registry-keys-from-the-command-line/) which seems promising.

Something like:

```
<?php

// Write the value you want to save to a .reg file
exec('reg import tweakExtension.reg');

?>
```

Ought to work.  A little more instruction on using the `reg` command can be gleaned by running `reg /?`.

<sub>* we hope...</sub>