# Installing win32std.dll file in PHP

Tags: php, windows, dll

Can anyone Please guide me how to install win32std dll file in xampp??
I've tried more then 5 times. working on windws. I've PHP 7.0 version!

Comment: I doubt an extension that hasn't been updated since 2003 will work on PHP 7.  You might be interested in https://github.com/sagebind/windows-registry.

Comment: Or just use `exec` and other tools for the underlying functionality (as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16699118/1072229)).

Comment: thnx! maybe i need to find other option!